Numpy division of 2 integers always leads to dtype `float64`
I want to predict the output dtype of a ufunc without executing it. To do this I rely on the ufunc.types list and casting rules of np.can_cast and np.result_type.
Everything was working fine until I tried to implement the divide ufunc.
In the following I want to predict the dtype of result = x1 / x2.
The "float" dtypes are giving the expected behaviour:



x1 dtype
x2 dtype
result dtype




float16
float16
float16


float16
float32
float32


float16
float64
float64


float16
float128
float128


float32
float16
float32


float32
float32
float32


float32
float64
float64


float32
float128
float128


float64
float16
float64


float64
float32
float64


float64
float64
float64


float64
float128
float128


float128
float16
float128


float128
float32
float128


float128
float64
float128


float128
float128
float128



The combination of a float and an integer also gives the expected result (whatever the order of the inputs are):



x1 dtype (float-like)
x2 dtype (int-like)
result dtype




float16
int8
float16


float16
int16
float32


float16
int32
float64


float16
int64
float64


float16
int64
float64


float16
uint8
float16


float16
uint16
float32


float16
uint32
float64


float16
uint64
float64


float16
uint64
float64


float32
int8
float32


float32
int16
float32


float32
int32
float64


float32
int64
float64


float32
int64
float64


float32
uint8
float32


float32
uint16
float32


float32
uint32
float64


float32
uint64
float64


float32
uint64
float64


float64
int8
float64


float64
int16
float64


float64
int32
float64


float64
int64
float64


float64
int64
float64


float64
uint8
float64


float64
uint16
float64


float64
uint32
float64


float64
uint64
float64


float64
uint64
float64


float128
int8
float128


float128
int16
float128


float128
int32
float128


float128
int64
float128


float128
int64
float128


float128
uint8
float128


float128
uint16
float128


float128
uint32
float128


float128
uint64
float128


float128
uint64
float128



However, combinations of two "integer" dtypes are all being cast to float64 (I tried all combinations of int8, int16, int32, int64, int64, uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64, uint64).
Has somebody an explanation of this behavior? For example as int8 can be cast to float16 it could also make sense that int8 / int8 -> float16. Why is everything just cast to float64 whatever the integer dtypes are?

In python 3 the default implementation of division gives you floating point division. I think numpy is following suite. If you want integer division you should us //

The use of FP numbers is expected since a/b perform a FP division in Python. You should use a//b if you want an integer division. This also applies in Numpy. If your question is why Numpy do not use smaller data-types for small integers, then It might just a missed optimization. By the way, I do not think FP16 is a good idea for an operation like int8/int8 as it may cause a loss of precision while the operation (alone) is expected to be rather precise. Not to mention 16-bit FP numbers are not supported efficiently on many machines (only ok for pretty recent machines).

As for 128-bit FP numbers, it is better to avoid it since it is not 128 bit on most machine. For example it is 64-bit on ARM and often 80-bit on x86-64 machines. So 32-bit and 64-bit FP numbers are the best option for such an int/int operation. They certainly choose 64-bit to avoid bugs or loss of precision (though it is less efficient than 32-bit ones). After all, CPython use 64-bit numbers for int/int operations, not 32-bit ones.

When you divide float to float numpy can assume that you want your output type to be the same as dividend or at least close to it (if divisor can be very big, you should be able to save 1/max_possible_divisor_value in output type, what means to have at list as much mantissa bits as divisor), and predict the desired output precision by your input dtypes. But when you divide int by int it cannot do this.
I mean when you calculate 1/3 you have infinite numbers in real answer, and if both arguments are int, you have no hints which can help you to decide, where to stop. That's why numpy just uses its default float type - float64. If you try to run this on some old 32-bit system, I think the result will be in float32 (UPD. last sentence is not true, thanks @JérômeRichard).

The rationale is relevant, but I do not think the last sentence is true. 64-bit FP numbers are also available on 32-bit systems and AFAIK FP-number typing rules are not dependent of the architecture in Numpy (as opposed to integers which do dependent of the architecture due to the C type like int). The only exception might be 128-bit float (the type should be the same but not its size). Thus, I think the answer is better without this sentence (unless you can prove it).

@JérômeRichard I think you are right. I thought that 32 and 64-bit system has different floats, but I cannot find any line in documentation about it (however, integer types are different).
